# YUI : how to retrieve XML datas from a local file?

Tags: javascript, xml, yui

I would like to read an XML file stored in the same directory as this HTML file :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="js/libs/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function lancement() {
            alert("début fonction");
            var myDS;
            YUI().use("datasource-io", "datatable-base", "datasource-xmlschema", "datatabledatasource", "io", "datasource-textschema", "datasource-get", function(Y) {
                myDS = new YAHOO.util.LocalDataSource('test.xml', {
                    responseType: YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_XML,
                    responseSchema: {
                        resultNode: "Customer",
                        totalRecords: "TotalCount",
                        fields: ["Name", "Id"]
                    }
                });
            });
            alert("fin fonction");
            alert(myDS.size());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="yui3-skin-sam" onload="lancement();">
    <p>HELLO</p>
    <div id="tab1"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<Customers>
    <TotalCount>1</TotalCount>
    <Customer><Name>John</Name><Id>1</Id></Customer>
</Customers>
```

but I never can read the number of lines.
do you know where does the error come from?

thanks

---

ok, I read a part of the tutorial and here is the result, which allows me to display a table but unfortunately without data inside (the XML file is the same) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!--<script src="js/libs/yui/yui-min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.13.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>


    <script >
        YUI().use("datasource-io", "datatable-base", "datasource-xmlschema", "io", "datasource-textschema", "datasource-get", "datasource", "datatable", "datatable-datasource", function(Y) {
            myDS2 = new Y.DataSource.IO({source: "test.xml"});
            myDS2.responseType = Y.DataSource.Type_XML;
//    myDS2.responseSchema = {
//        resultNode: "Customer",
//        totalRecords: "TotalCount",
//        fields: ["Name", "Id"]
//    };
            myDS2.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceXMLSchema, {
                schema: {
                    resultListLocator: "result",
                    resultFields: [
                        {key: "Name", locator: "*[local-name() ='Name']"},
                        {key: "Id", locator: "*[local-name() ='Id']"}

                    ]
                }
            });
            var myColumnDefs = [
                {key: "Name", sortable: true, resizeable: true},
                {key: "Id", sortable: true, resizeable: true}];
            var myDataTable = new Y.DataTable({
                columns: myColumnDefs, data: myDS2});
            myDataTable.render("#tab1");
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body class="yui3-skin-sam">
    <p>HELLO</p>
    <div id="tab1"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the DataSourceXMLSchema :

```
 myDS2.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceXMLSchema, {
            schema: {
                resultListLocator: "Customers/Customer",
                resultFields: [
                    {key: "Name", locator: "Name"},
                    {key: "Id", locator: "Id"}

                ]
            }
```

Comment: thanks but I passed to JQuery and I no more use YUI...maybe it will be of interest for someone else...